# How to fix sudo when user is already in a group that is listed in sudoers file?

Tags: terminal, sudo

I am on MacOS Ventura 13.2. Since this update I cannot perform `sudo` anymore:

```
❯ sudo touch /test
Password:
est is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

It doesn't make sense, because my user is in the admin group and this group is configured for `sudo` in `/etc/sudoers`

```
❯ grep admin /etc/sudoers
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL
❯ ls -la /etc/sudoers
-r--r-----@ 1 root  wheel  1563 31 Jan 13:50 /etc/sudoers
❯ groups | sed -n 's/.* \(admin\) .*/\1/p'
admin
❯ id -a
uid=2114643402(est) gid=983846816 groups=983846816,0(wheel),12(everyone),62(netaccounts),80(admin),204(_developer),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),400(com.apple.access_remote_ae),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
```

However If I add `est ALL = (ALL) ALL` to `/etc/sudoers` `sudo` works

```
❯ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for est on ***:
    env_reset, env_keep+=BLOCKSIZE, env_keep+="COLORFGBG COLORTERM", env_keep+=__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING, env_keep+="CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME",
    env_keep+="LINES COLUMNS", env_keep+=LSCOLORS, env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK, env_keep+=TZ, env_keep+="DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY", env_keep+="EDITOR VISUAL", env_keep+="HOME MAIL", lecture_file=/etc/sudo_lecture

User est may run the following commands on ***:
    (ALL) ALL
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't work with the group entry and how to fix it?

Comment: What does `id -a` return?

Comment: @nohillside please see my updated question

Comment: It looks like the admin line in `sudoers` is commented out.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @allan the % is the group indicator, not a comment character (which is #).

Comment: Is this a local user, the user is seems to be rather high for this?

Comment: Looks like that's a so-called mobile account, probably created using Active Directory – I see two labels "Admin" and "Mobile" for my account under "System Settings > Users & Groups". I don't know for certain because the initial setup has been made by a company administrator.
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-configure-mobile-accounts-mh32157/mac

Comment: That looks like `sudo` is taking "/t" as a command-line option.  The user it claims is not in `/etc/sudoers` is "est".

Comment: @MarcWilson the user seems to be called est, according to id -a.

Comment: Talk about a coincidence.